# override delete_selected to check for records that exist in other tables in django 1.10

Tags: django

I am using the default admin dashboard of django. Basically, i want to override the delete_selected method on a model by model basis so I can check for records before allowing the deletion to take place.

My models.py is:

```
class Kind(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    addedby = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='admin_kind')
    createdon = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedon = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)


class Item(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    kind = models.ForeignKey(Kind,related_name="item_kind")
    createdon = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedon = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' , '.join([self.kind.name, self.name])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('kind', 'name',)
        unique_together = (('name','kind'))
```

Now what I want is before a kind could be deleted, I want to check if there is a related record in items. If there is, do not delete it.

But i am stuck at how to go about overriding delete_selected method in admin.py.

```
def delete_selected(self, request, obj):
    '''
    Delete Kind only if there are no items under it.
    '''
    for o in obj.all():
        featuredItems = Item.objects.filter(kind=o).count()
        if featuredItems == 0:
            o.delete()
```

However, django shows the warning and when i click yes, it deletes the kind even though there are records for it. I want to absolutely block the deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are trying to write a lot of code for something that can be done merely by adding an attribute to your model field

[PROTECT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT)
Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising ProtectedError, a subclass of django.db.IntegrityError.

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    kind=models.ForeignKey(Kind,related_name="item_kind", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

What you are trying to achieve is made even more difficult by the fact that django displays a confirmation page on delete.

Answer (score 1):

Function code is correct, but you need to explicitly tell django to use your own function to delete that model's objects. You can do that by declaring a list in your admin.py,

```
actions = ['delete_selected']
```

Where "delete_selected" is your function name.